# List the struct fields and methods dynamically

Tags: go

How to list the fields and methods of a struct, in GoLang dynamically? For eg, I want to get the output as id, name, age, and all the method names.

```
type Student struct {
    id int
    name string
    age int
}

func (s *Student) setId(i int) {
    s.id = i
}

func (s *Student) getId() int {
    return s.id
}

func (s *Student) setName(n string) {
    s.name = n
}

func (s *Student) getName() string {
    return s.name
}

func (s *Student) setAge(a int) {
    s.age = a
}

func (s *Student) getAge() int {
    return s.age
}

func main() {
    st := Student{1,"Jack",22}
    fmt.Println(st.getId()," ",st.getName()," ",st.getAge())

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just interested in a string representation of the object and want to implement the `Stringer` interface?

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [How to print struct with String() of fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142594/how-to-print-struct-with-string-of-fields)

Comment: Package reflect is your friend here.

Answer (score 4):

To get information about a struct at runtime, you have to use the package `reflect`. First, get the type of the struct, and then you can iterate through it. However, with your example, be aware that the type `main.Student` doesn't have any methods associated, but the type `*main.Student` has.

Here is an example of how you can fetch those information:

```
func main() {
    s := Student{1, "Jack", 22}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    ptr_t := reflect.TypeOf(&s)

    methods := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < ptr_t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        methods = append(methods, ptr_t.Method(i).Name)
    }

    fields := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fields = append(fields, t.Field(i).Name)
    }

    fmt.Println(methods)
    # [getAge getId getName setAge setId setName]
    fmt.Println(fields)
    # [id name age]

}
```

A point about your code: look at how the export of fields and methods between package is done. Because all the fields and methods starting by a lowercase letter are not accessible outside of the package. You have to start them with an uppercase letter.

Another point: there are usually no getters and setters in Go code. If you want to read and write a struct field, simply start it with an uppercase letter.