# Print all properties of struct even through that struct has a default string representation?

Tags: go

Normally, I can print all properties of an object with:

```
c.Infof("car: %+v", car)
```

But one struct has a `String()` method. I think that this causes the line above to only print what the `String()` method returns.

How can I override this and force print all properties of that struct?

Comment: Please, what are you trying to achieve exactly ? The question is unclear actually.

Comment: Also paste a code snippet.

Comment: I didnt know it would be so unclear. Ill post it tomorrow, when Im at my computer again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print struct with String() of fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142594/how-to-print-struct-with-string-of-fields)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy workaround is to use the `%#v` verb:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type someStruct struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func (someStruct) String() string {
    return "this is the end"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", someStruct{1, 2})
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", someStruct{1, 2})
}
```

This prints:

```
this is the end
main.someStruct{a:1, b:2}
```

Comment: @RickyA: it helps to read through the [`fmt` documentation:](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) `%#v a Go-syntax representation of the value`. (note that `%#v` is also modifiable via the GoStringer interface)